# AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'

Tags: python, django, heroku, tastypie, sentry

I keep getting the below errors in my sentry exceptions

`AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'`

And the trace only points to code withing the django code base without pointing to any place in my application. My logs are clean too. What could be a possible reason for this?

```
        raise Resolver404({'path' : path})
     @property
     def urlconf_module(self):
         try:
             return self._urlconf_module
         except AttributeError:
             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
             return self._urlconf_module
     @property
'self'  
<RegexURLResolver urls (None:None) ^/>
```

Comment: Looks like you are invoking the regexresolver of a class before it is initialized. It could be a dependancy issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I haven't changed anything relevant to urls and this error started appearing. Any idea how I can go about debugging this?

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise on the Internet I found this:

> The issue is caused by an import ordering problem, in your example code you call urlresolvers.reverse which will load example/urls.py, which will trigger an admin.autodiscover() call, which will load social/apps/django_app/default/admin.py, which will try to load your custom user model which will fail to load your user model.

I hit the problem when I called a function directly from `views.py`, and this function resulted in use of `resolve`, which probably lead to an import problem since calling a function directly from `views.py` is bad style.  However, the comment above helped med debug the issue.

Comment: You probably found it here: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/269