# urls.py isn't working in Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

Im Trying to deploy my app on `Pythonanywhere`. when i'm importing the following `Django` classes, it won't recognize them (it works great on my local server):

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
```

from urls.py:

```
"""general URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Add an import:  from blog import urls as blog_urls
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include(blog_urls))
"""
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from adray import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='home'),
   url(r'^happen/$', views.happen , name='happen'),
   url(r'^simulate/$', views.simulate , name='simulate'),
   url(r'^run/$', views.happen , name='run'),
   url(r'^existing/$', views.existing , name='existing'),
  # url(r'^inspired/$', views.inspired , name='inspired'),
]
```

error.log:

```
2015-07-13 04:28:26,107 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-07-13 04:28:26,107 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 358, in urlconf_module
2015-07-13 04:28:26,107 :    return self._urlconf_module
2015-07-13 04:28:26,107 :AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'
2015-07-13 04:28:26,108 :
```

My question is: do i need to load anything configure some thing in order to make them work?

Comment: Maybe [this issue](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/269) is relevant? It looks the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255561/attributeerror-regexurlresolver-object-has-no-attribute-urlconf-module) other question without an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong version of Django. The code is commented as being for Django 1.8, but the exception comes from the built-in Django that is installed on PythonAnywhere for Python 3.3 and that's version 1.6.6.

Comment: Thanks! how can i upgrade to Django 1.8 in PythonAnywhere?

Comment: There are docs in the PythonAnywhere help pages about using virtualenvs for your web apps.